# When does the day reset?

Tags: support

When does the day reset? I'm asking purely out of curiosity because for me (living on the East Coast U.S.A) it seems that the day resets anytime from 8pm-10pm. When is the official day reset?

Answer (score 7):

Stack Exchange runs on UTC (GMT +0:00).

This means if you're in EST, all Stack Exchange sites will roll over at 19:00 or 20:00 EST (dependent on DST)

Comment: You can see the current time in UTC by clicking the down arrow beside your name in the top bar.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that it's currently DST in GMT land, so the time on the site is an hour behind us. (ie. site says 3am right now, but it's actually 4am)

Comment: @AnnaLear I did not know that! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: There is no DST in GMT. UK is on BST now.

Comment: @alexanderpas But there **is** in EST, which means what time 0:00 is "changes", from an EST perspective.

Comment: There's EST and EDT. 0:00 never changes in GMT land.

Comment: @AshleyNunn That thing is so handy, I'm surprised we haven't put it in a tooltip somewhere instead. ;)

Comment: @alexanderpas `it seems that the day resets anytime from 8pm-10pm.` The OP lives in an area that swaps between EST and EDT. This is what makes 0:00 ***appear*** to change.